# cron job not running bash script

Tags: linux, bash, script, cron

The script runs fine when called manually by the user. It looks like not even the `rm` commands are being executed by the cron job.

In `crontab -e`:

```
10 22 * * * /bin/bash /x/y/z/s/path/to/script
```

And this is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Clean up
/bin/rm -rf /z/y/z/a/b/current/*
cd /z/y/z/a/to/
/bin/rm -rf ?s??/D????
cd /z/y/z/s/

# Find the latest file
FILE=`/usr/bin/ssh user@server /bin/ls -ht /x/y/z/t/a/ | /usr/bin/head -n 1`

# Copy over the latest archive and place it in the proper directory
/usr/bin/rsync -avz -e /urs/bin/ssh user@server:"/x/y/z/t/a/$FILE" /x/y/z/t/a/

# Unzip the zip file and place it in the proper directory
/usr/bin/unzip -o /x/y/z/t/a/$FILE -d /x/y/z/t/a/current/

# Run Dev's script
cd /x/y/z/t/
./old.py a/current/ t/ 5
```

Comment: Cron explains problems with crontab files or script executions defined therein via syslog. Attach the relevant lines from `/var/log/syslog` (You should find such lines with a timestamp of expected execution time - or the edit time of the crontab) to your post.

Comment: I don't have a /var/log/syslog file.  I'm working on red hat btw

Comment: @J doe afaik cron has its own log file there, try `/var/log/cron`?

Comment: Yes, there is a log file /var/log/cron  It only shows begin edit end, reload, basic stuff like that.  i never see my cron job mentioned besides the stuff above in this comment

Comment: You are aware this command is scheduled to `22:10` (i.e. about 10 PM), not `10:22`, right? Just checking.

Comment: Yea, I keep changing to the time trying to get it to work

Comment: Since you're on red hat, try inspecting the logs with `journalctl`. Specifically try `journalctl _COMM=cron`.

Comment: Nothing came back when I ran those commands.  Here is the version i'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: What are the script's permissions? Are you allowed to run it as the user for which you've edited the crontab?

Comment: I chmod +x the script and running it as ./script.sh works just fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everybody for the help.  I figured it out.

I'm use to working in cst time and the server was in gmt time.

Comment: Servers are almost always GMT (or rather UTC). Much better to have one universal time in logs and translater to the users local time (and language) in their clients. So expect to see this on more servers.